# Twirl dependencies required for scalatra project using Gradle/Mill

Tags: scala, twirl, mill

For a web application, I am using scalatra. **Mill** is my build tool of choice. To render UI, I am considering twirl template engine. However, all the examples/references that I have come through only show twirl using sbt.

What all twirl dependencies are required for a non-sbt project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [`TwirlModule`](https://com-lihaoyi.github.io/mill/mill/Contrib_Plugins.html#_twirl) which is part of the `mill-contrib-twirllib` plugin. It handles compilation of twirl templates and configuration of imports and formats.

To get a list of twirl dependencies (used by mill) you can consult the `TwirlModule.twirlClasspath` target.

```scala
Agg(
  ivy"com.typesafe.play::twirl-compiler:${twirlVersion()}",
  ivy"org.scala-lang.modules::scala-parser-combinators:1.1.0"
)
```